# Automatically open "browser" when double-clicking file

Tags: bash, user-interface, ubuntu, root-framework

Admittedly, the title is not very conclusive… I'm working with CERNs framework for data analysis [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) on an ubuntu machine. The generated data is stored in so-called root files (*.root). To open and browse such a file, I need to open a terminal, load the file and open a (T)Browser. In code:

```
$ root
root[0] TFile *f=new TFile("my_file.root")
root[1] new TBrowser() // opens GUI
```

Equivalently, I can also just do

```
$ root my_file.root
root[0] new TBrowser() // opens GUI
```

but this is still tedious. Therefore, I'd like to just double click the respective file(s) (or call `xdg-open my_file.root` in the terminal, respectively) and automatically open the GUI, i.e., execute the little script above. How can I do this in Ubuntu? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions and this is more of a desktop question. I would ask at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) instead.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. I'll move the question to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: fwiw you can directly instantiate the TBrowser from the command line through the `-e` option. e.g. `root my_file.root -e 'TBrowser b'`

Comment: Has anyone found a way to open TBrowser without having to always open the commandline?
Why can't I just double click on the .root file and open the TBrowser that way?